# How to associate multiple file in music player in c#

Tags: c#, associations, audio-player

I Recently Developed a music player in c# WindowsFormsApplications.

Everything is going good only when you choose the program to default, it can open one music file perfectly but when you select 5 music files. 5 music player open.

How to fix this to open multiple file when you set it default like a play list in c#?
And I did not tried any thing or any code to do that.
please help!

this is my Program.cs

```
  static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        //with args(user open file with the program)
        if (args != null && args.Length > 0)
        {

            string fileName = args[0];
            //Check file exists
            if (File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Form1 MainFrom = new Form1();
                MainFrom.OpenFile(fileName);
                Application.Run(MainFrom);
            }
            //The file does not exist
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The file does not exist!", "BMPlayer Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }
        }
        //without args
        else
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

And This is Form1.cs to open file

```
public void OpenFile(string filePath)
    {
        string file1 = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = filePath;
    }
```

Comment: a little COde wouldn´t hurt, how do you do your selection/load ? do you have any sort of title list in your application ?

Comment: Since you showed 0 lines of code, I can only assume what's been troubling you. I think you should handle mutliple filenames in `Main` method of your application (in `Program.cs`)

Comment: this code work for one file

Comment: you need to activate multifile selection

Comment: there is no way to activate multifile selection

Answer (score 1):

The best approach to you it's you create a new filetype (Playlist) and receive as parameter in your application, then you can manage this file inside your application adding/removing songs from this playlist.
A good approach it's store the content in JSon format. then you can manage the content easily using Nuget Packages eg: NewtonSoft.

I created a simple code example then you can create and manage your playlists using json and Music Object.

```
   private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string line;

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"c:\temp\music\playlist.mpl"))
        {
            line = reader.ReadLine();
        }

        var jobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Music>>(line);
    }

    private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var musiclist = new List<Music>();

        var objSongs = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp\music\");

        foreach (var song in objSongs)
        {
            musiclist.Add(new Music { Name = song });
        }

        var ret = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(musiclist);

        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\temp\music\playlist.mpl"))
        {
            sw.Write(ret);
            sw.Flush();
        }
    }

public class Music
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sure, hold on. :)

Comment: shared, please take a look.

Comment: thank you very much.but it does not help me.Again thanks!

Comment: plaese help, i can't fix this :(